# Account Problem

Tags: bug, user-accounts, login

My apologies for the fact that this post is totally off topic, but there is no apparent alternative.

I cannot log in to math.stackexchange.  Because I cannot log in, I cannot post to meta.  I'm therefore hoping that someone with the appropriate privileges can move this post to meta and/or help me get my account back.

When I log in (with the username/password I've always used) nothing happens.  I tried resetting my password, but the problem continued just as before.

My username is WillO and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29145/willo) is my account.

Help?

PS--- I've had to enter a fake email in order to post this query, because when I enter my actual email, I'm told I can't use that because it's associated with an existing account!

Comment: OK --- I deleted all my stackexchange cookies and tried again, and now I'm in.  Problem solved, though I still don't understand what caused it.

Comment: ---- and the problem recurred, and I deleted cookies again, and now I'm back in again......

Comment: See my answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19337/18398).

Answer (score 2):

The SE team is now revising their login system to be better across the network. I experienced a similar issue a few days ago.

This means that if you have more than one login over the network, used simultaneously, you won't be able to login on any of the sites (which was the problem I faced).

To solve this, clear the cookie called "acct" from the stackexchange domain. Then login only one account. If you want to login on the other, log out first.

Comment: You can also consider using multiple browsers and/or private/incognito mode.

Comment: Originally, I wanted to write "one account per browser", but I figured that it'd be better to just write it like this. But you're very correct.

Comment: Yes, the problem has recurred and I'm back to being unable to log in (unless I open a separate browser, which is not something I'll be willing to do every day).  Presumably this is because I use my browser to log in to other stackexchange sites with a different login name.  So apparently I have to choose between staying active on one set of sites or on the other.  This is incredibly obnoxious.

Comment: @WillO: I can relate to that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Yes, I'm afraid i won't be back.  It is astonishing to me that Stackexchange would treat its users so cavalierly, especially when it relies on them for 100% of its content.  But so be it.

Comment: @Will: I wholeheartedly recommend that you contact the SE community managers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Does the following post constitute the contact you recommend, or did you have something else in mind?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260485/cant-log-in-to-some-sites/260491   (Thanks for your concern, by the way.)

Comment: @Will: That seems about enough. Although it seems that you weren't quite satisfied of the response that you received. Let me point out, again, that the new system only allows you to use login across the network at a time. If you have accounts on several sites with the same login, this shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had the same problem (I am both AAron's). You can use the same email for two different accounts, as long as you use the forgot password thing. You have to start all over, but thats the only solution I got. Sorry dude